# Respawning enemies from other scenes in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im probably go about this the wrong way, but i've hit a road block. In my game sitting at a souls like camp fire should respawn all enemies with a certain type on them and I cant think of a way to get this to work from other scenes when the player has rested.

I've created the respawning script but it only works when resting in the same room as the enemy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyCore;
    private Core core;

    enum DeathType { respawnOnEnter, respawnOnRest, neverRespawn}
    [SerializeField] DeathType deathType;

    private Death Death => death ? death : core.GetCoreComponent(ref death);
    private Death death;

    private bool canRespawn = true;
    private bool justRested = false;
    private bool justRespawned = false;


    public void Start()
    {

        core = enemyCore.GetComponent<Core>();

     

        if (ES3.KeyExists(core.transform.parent.gameObject.name + "canRespawn"))
            canRespawn = ES3.Load<bool>(core.transform.parent.gameObject.name + "canRespawn");

        if (ES3.KeyExists("justRested"))
            canRespawn = ES3.Load<bool>("justRested");


        switch (deathType)
        {
            case DeathType.respawnOnEnter:
                canRespawn = true;
                break;

            case DeathType.respawnOnRest:

                if(justRested || justRespawned)
                {
                    canRespawn = true;
                    justRespawned = false;
                }


                break;
        }

        ES3.Save(core.transform.parent.gameObject.name + "canRespawn", canRespawn);

        if (!canRespawn)
        {
            core.transform.parent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void Rested()
    {
        justRested = true;
        justRespawned = true;

        ES3.Save("justRested", justRested);

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(Death.JustDied)
        {
            switch (deathType)
            {
                case DeathType.respawnOnEnter:
                    canRespawn = true;
                    break;

                case DeathType.respawnOnRest:
                    canRespawn = false;
                    break;

                case DeathType.neverRespawn:
                    canRespawn = false;
                    break;

            }


            ES3.Save(core.transform.parent.gameObject.name + "canRespawn", canRespawn);

            Death.JustDied = false;

        }

        switch (deathType)
        {
            case DeathType.respawnOnRest:

                if (justRested)
                {
                    canRespawn = true;

                    justRested = false;
                   
                    ES3.Save(core.transform.parent.gameObject.name + "canRespawn", canRespawn);
                }

                break;
        }

    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PlayerRestState.RestAction += Rested;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerRestState.RestAction -= Rested;
    }


}
```

Heres the code I have written, the script should go on each enemy individually.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There’s a couple of ways, such as using multiple scenes, or a `DontDestroyOnLoad` But, this sounds like a use-case for a `ScriptableObject` to help you persist your Enemy data between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using scriptable objects meaning I could access data from any enemy from any scene. If anyone was wondering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).